# Symfony command line program output from service

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony service that processes a file and does stuff with its information. I call this service from a controller and separately from a command class. The actual service takes a long time to run, and I'd like to show some status output on the command line while it processes the file.  What is the best way to accomplish this without adding echo commands in my service?

Edit
This seems to be the solution: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-show-logs-in-console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are commands like

```
$output->write('Blah blah blah');

$output->writeLn('Blah blah blah'); // Above with a line break
```

You can also add colours and progress bars and possibly other stuff that I've never got round to using.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#coloring-the-output

**UPDATE**

You could use the `EventDisptcher` service to update your command on events in your service.
For example...

You command

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    //....

    $dispatcher = $this->getContainer->get('event_dispatcher');

    $dispatcher->addListener(
        'an.event.that.you.have.set.up', 
        function (GenericEvent $event) use ($output) {
            $output->writeLn('<info>This event has happened</info');
        }
    });

    //....
}
```

Your service

```
protected $dispatcher;

//....

public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher, ...)
{
    $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    //...
}

public function someFunction()
{
    //...

    $variable = 'something you are using');

    $dispatcher->dispatch(
        'an.event.that.you.have.set.up', 
        new GenericEvent($variable)
    );

    //...
}
```

Obviously there would be a lot more to both you command your service but this give the basic of how to tie it all together.

An actual use example can be seen here..

Command - https://github.com/Richtermeister/Sylius/blob/subscription-bundle/src/Sylius/Bundle/SubscriptionBundle/Command/ProcessSubscriptionsCommand.php

Service - https://github.com/Richtermeister/Sylius/blob/subscription-bundle/src/Sylius/Bundle/SubscriptionBundle/Processor/SubscriptionProcessor.php

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, however, I am calling a service that can be run from different areas of my app, so I cannot pepper it with $output commands.  The solution is what I listed - add the logger and then hook the logger output to the console.

Comment: If you are doing the processing in different services you could use the event dispatcher service. I will updated my answer with that way.

Comment: Much more elegant than my method :)

Comment: To be honest it had never occurred to me until I saw it on the Sylius PR. ALl of my none command stuff was just filled with dirty `echo ..."\n";`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the solution: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-show-logs-in-console